# Create different distribution types with setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Given the following (demonstration) project layout:

```
MyProject/
    README
    LICENSE
    setup.py
    myproject/
        ... # packages
    extrastuff/
        ... # some extra data
```

How (and where) do I declare different distribution types? Especially I need these two options:

1. A distribution containing only the source
2. A distribution containing the source and all data files under (extrastuff)

Ideally, how do I declare the upper two configuration whereas the second one depends on the first one?

Comment: Why not create different `setup.py` files?  The source distribution is available as `sdist`.

Comment: @Brian: I am aware of `sdist`, thanks. I'm maintainer of a mid-scale open source project, and I'd like to adhere to common conventions (like having one `setup.py` which manages packaging/installing). I really want to see a solution which just uses one setup script.

Comment: I cannot provide details because I haven't had that kind of problem before. One approach could be provide your own `sdist` command that just calls the old `sdist` with different metadata that depends on the target distribution. The distribution could be provided as an option from the command line or using `platform.linux_distribution` to get the same target distribution as the one in the machine calling `setup.py` by default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've implemented something like this before ... the `sdist` command can be extended to handle additional command line arguments and to manipulate the data files based on these. If you run `python setup.py sdist --help`, it'll include your custom command line arguments in the help, which is nice. Use the following recipe:

```
from distutils import log
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist

class CustomSdist(sdist):

    user_options = [
        ('packaging=', None, "Some option to indicate what should be packaged")
    ] + sdist.user_options

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sdist.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.packaging = "default value for this option"

    def get_file_list(self):

        log.info("Chosen packaging option: {self.packaging}".format(self=self))

        # Change the data_files list here based on the packaging option
        self.distribution.data_files = list(
          ('folder', ['file1', 'file2'])
        )
        sdist.get_file_list(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    setup(
        name = "name",
        version = "version",
        author = "author",
        author_email = "author_email",
        url = "url",
        py_modules = [
            # ...
        ],
        packages = [
            # ...
        ],
#        data_files = default data files for commands other than sdist if you wish
        cmdclass={
            'sdist': CustomSdist
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that solution, I think I'll go for that one.

Answer (score 3):

You could extend setup.py to additionally include some custom command line parsing. You could then catch a custom argument and strip it out so that it won't affect `setuptools`.

You can access the command line argument in `sys.argv`. As for modifying the call to `setuptools.setup()`, I recommend creating a dictionary of arguments to pass, modifying the dictionary based on the command line arguments, and then calling `setup()` using the `**dict` notation, like so:

```
from setuptools import setup
import sys

basic = {'name': 'my program'}
extra = {'bonus': 'content'}

if '--extras' in sys.argv:
    basic.update(extra)
    sys.argv.remove('--extras')

setup(**basic)
```

For more thorough command line parsing you could also use the [`getopt` module](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html), or the newer [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) if you're only targeting Python 2.7 and higher.

**EDIT**: I also found a section in the distutils documentation titled [Creating a new Distutils command](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#creating-a-new-distutils-command). That may also be a helpful resource.

Comment: I've found that the `sdist` command (from distutils) complains about unknown command line arguments if you try this sort of thing.

Comment: I just tested this using the feedparser project's setup.py file by using the `--extras` option to change the name of the project (and consequently the output filename). It worked without an error. Did you try modifying `sys.argv` before calling the `setup()` function?

Comment: This is a nice and simple solution, so +1 for that. I think wutz mentioned earlier, that it is possible to create custom distutils commands. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @KurtMcKee Ah, you're removing the extra stuff from `sys.argv` - didn't catch that. Then it should work nicely!