# Python packaging with alternative setup.py

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

Is it possible to indicate that a specific file will become setup.py during the building process (e.g., `python setup.py sdist`) when using `distutils` (or `distribute`, or else) ?

I would like to be able to do `python setup-specificbuild.py sdist` and have something (either in `setup-specificbuild.py` or as a command line argument) that would rename `setup-specificbuild.py` to `setup.py` in the package tarball build in `dist/`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer on SO about a similar problem ([create different distribution types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064823/create-different-distribution-types-with-setup-py)). Custom command line parsing seems to be a decent workaround, and then eventual distribution-specific logic can be pushed to separate modules, only imported if found, and only included when needed.

Answer (score 0):

`setup.py` is ultimately just an entry point to a Python program, so if you want to implement branching build behaviors, just have your standard `setup.py` parse command line arguments and dispatch the actual build process to whatever modules you want.  That's much preferable to trying to dynamically re-name files with some pre-build script step.

Comment: The unwanted side effect with this is approach that the final `setup.py` will contain all branching rules, which are all irrelevant when shipping one source build.

Comment: @Igautier: No, that's backwards. A source build should contain all branching rules.

Comment: And even if for some reason you want to be that controlling and pedantic about it, you can implement the switching logic in another module, have `setup.py` delegate to that module, then have that module delegate to each platform specific build module.  You can then have the platform builders build distributions excluding all files other than themselves, and have `setup.py` wildcard import the setup submodules, and when no platform is specified, just run the first one it finds.  In your platform specific builds, you'll only have the single platform setup module, so you'll be good to go.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Not quite. A source build is only different from a binary build in the sense that it will be compiled when installed, at the difference of a source tree that will contain everything needed to  make any build.

Comment: @lgautier: In the Python world, that difference does not exist. A source distribution should work on all platforms, and therefore contain all branching rules. Anything else is seen as a "binary" build, even if it in fact only contains Python source.

Comment: @sr2222: Nothing about being pedantic or controlling, more about being able to ship clean builds free of unreachable code. Otherwise, I agree that there does not seem much of a way outside of a "package generation" system (the one you suggest, or a code-generation tool that would create a `setup.py` and call it).

Comment: setup.py *is* the package generation system. Having a package generation system to generate a package generation system seems a bit silly. :-)

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, it runs on a VM.  If you ship a Python source distribution, it should install and run on any compatible VM.  For the purposes of source distributions, the VM is really the platform, not the OS the VM is running on.  It would be like shipping a compiled program for Windows with different versions for people with different display resolutions.  Sure the code for rendering a WQXGA image will be unreachable on a machine with a XGA display, but that's below the level of abstraction you as a program distributor should be concerned with.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I surely got myself into a bike shed argument ;-). May be touching on interesting points though. The package generation system is, probably by design and there were certainly valid reasons for that limitation at the time, only making it possible to generate one package from a source tree. With this, it is enforcing the idea that source tree and package builds are the same thing.

Comment: @sr2222: I think that this is collapsing the notions of source package build (something that one will be able to install), and source tree (the code base, normally the result of `checkout` or `clone` with a VCS). One example is when one wants to generate several source package out a source tree. One might argue that such several packages should see their common code spun out into a separate package but that's not always practical (as it is introducing a version dependency).

Comment: And I would say for a source build, the different versions would be Python2, Python3, Jython, etc, not the system OS.  The core CPython distribution follows this pattern; there are `if platform ==` type blocks throughout the core libraries, even though the libraries are installed alongside the interpreter, and thus could be differentiated by platform pretty easily.  It seems like if it's good enough for the core libraries, it should be good enough for programs written on top of them.

Comment: @sr2222: Not sure to follow... may be the comment was for an other question ?

Comment: No, I was responding to your comment.  I was saying that if you look at the core Python distribution, you will see all sorts of places where behavior branches based upon OS, even though they could conceivably structure the OS-specific builds to include only code for the OS the interpreter they are bundled with is compiled for.  My argument was given this, following the same general principle of distributing code that is platform independent (by branching based upon platform internally) should probably be looked at as the law of the land when it comes to Python programs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30590/discussion-between-lgautier-and-sr2222)